# Bash column altering

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tr, netflow

I have some data in columns, however some data is confusing my column numbers making bash opperations confusing, the data below is what I am working with (however there are over 1 million lines of). I am interested in the numbers in 8th and 9th column:

```
2014-05-10 08:47:57.373  3600.633 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->      42.209.2.47:52436    1.3 M    1.8 G     1
2014-05-10 09:50:39.609  3601.385 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->   60.120.101.149:47403    1.0 M    1.5 G     1
2014-05-10 10:00:14.064  3607.106 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->    46.83.205.250:32307    2.0 M    3.0 G     1
2014-05-10 10:03:04.263  3644.192 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->       1.32.33.64:10933   987743    1.4 G     1
2014-05-10 11:07:16.247   546.764 TCP      105.51.244.36:80    ->   114.31.255.222:55580   797919    1.2 G     1
2014-05-10 10:46:15.190  2332.334 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->     43.95.27.215:53394    1.1 M    1.7 G     1
2014-05-10 11:00:49.005  1458.456 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->   39.150.172.138:39326    1.2 M    1.7 G     1
2014-05-09 23:53:03.625    56.271 ICMP    61.114.116.140:3     ->    114.31.255.88:0.3          2      318     1
2014-05-09 23:53:59.833     0.000 UDP      114.31.255.88:15360 ->    24.56.237.230:24752        1      131     1
2014-05-09 23:53:59.835     0.000 UDP      114.31.255.88:15360 ->    154.115.89.25:28904        1      131     1
2014-05-09 23:53:59.767     0.174 TCP      105.51.244.40:80    ->    114.31.255.41:28520       13     6675     1
2014-05-09 23:53:59.409     0.000 UDP      114.31.255.70:53    ->   114.31.255.244:54604        1      536     1
2014-05-09 23:53:59.621     0.333 TCP      105.51.244.40:80    ->    114.31.255.41:28519       16     7034     1
```

I use tr to make data processing easier by turning all spaces into one:

```
tr -s ' '
```

Which makes using (below) easier:

```
cut -f [column number(s)] -d ' '
```

However when a value has a G or an M it confuses colum numbering. I would like to change for example:

```
2014-05-10 11:00:49.005  1458.456 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->   39.150.172.138:39326    1.2 M    1.7 G   1
```

to

```
2014-05-10 11:00:49.005  1458.456 UDP      114.31.255.90:57844 ->   39.150.172.138:39326    1.2M    1.7G   1
```

I have tried

```
tr ' G ' 'G '
tr ' M ' 'M '
```

Also using [:space:] in different configurations however I have not succeeded.

Comment: `tr` operates on *single characters* to make those sort of changes you need `sed` or `awk` or similar.

Comment: Not sure from where you get that data but maybe its possible to output it not in human readable form (without `M` and `G`...)? Aside of ` M` ` G` problem you can use `awk '{ print $8 $9 }'` to print 8th and 9th column.

Comment: It is a netflow output, given to me, not produced by me, I am to analyse it unfortunately!

Comment: This looks like it would be better suited for `awk`s fixed-length fields support (read `man awk` and look for the parts about `FIELDWIDTHS`...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` doesn't work like `sed` as it translates character by characters. Use `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/ \([MG] \)/\1/g'
```

**Explanation:**

```
/ \([MG] \)/  # match space followed by letter M or G and followed by another space.
              # Also capture matched letter in matched group #1
\1            # replace by back-reference #1
```

Comment: An explanation of the characters used could help others in the future, but thank you, it works perfectly.